# javascript/npm install path resolved incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I'm starting my work on a JS project, where I want to use bower, grunt and so on. `qunit-sinon` is the main directory of my project:

```
tducin@home:~/Development/qunit-sinon (grunt)$ ll
razem 192
drwxrwxr-x 5 tducin tducin   4096 sie 24 11:45 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 tducin tducin   4096 sie 23 18:00 ../
drwxrwxr-x 5 tducin tducin   4096 sie 23 18:18 bower_components/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin    458 sie 23 18:15 bower.json
drwxrwxr-x 8 tducin tducin   4096 sie 24 11:42 .git/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin    552 sie 23 20:46 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin   1148 sie 24 11:41 Gruntfile.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin    485 sie 23 18:26 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin   1079 sie 23 20:45 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x 4 tducin tducin   4096 sie 24 11:46 node_modules/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin 140356 sie 24 11:45 npm-debug.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin    346 sie 24 11:44 package.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin    324 sie 23 18:30 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tducin tducin   1402 sie 24 11:00 tests.js
```

I've got following installed globally: node/npm, bower, grunt-cli. I used `grunt-init gruntfile` to initialize my `Gruntfile.js`. The content of my `package.json` is:

```
tducin@home:~/Development/qunit-sinon (grunt)$ cat package.json 
{
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/qunit-sinon"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1"
  }
}
```

Now I want to run `npm install` to install all missing modules (few grunt plugins there were automatically added to Gruntfile.js), tut then I get following error:

```
tducin@home:~/Development/qunit-sinon (grunt)$ npm install
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/tducin/.npm/underscore/1.6.0'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/tducin/.npm/underscore/1.6.0']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/tducin/.npm/underscore/1.6.0',
npm ERR!   parent: 'jshint' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-34-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/tducin/Development/qunit-sinon
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! path /home/tducin/.npm/underscore/1.6.0
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/tducin/.npm/underscore/1.6.0'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tducin/Development/qunit-sinon/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

npm want to install globally - that's why he wants to have administrator privileges. But it's not what I want to do.

I'm pretty sure that the reason for this error is very obvious, yet, I don't know it. Please explain me why is npm trying to install in `/home/tducin/.npm` (global) instead of my local project `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Can you check who is the owner of the ~/.npm directory? It seems that everything else is OK.  
If the owner of the directory is not the current user that would be it - just change the ownership.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Comment: you were right - it was the permissions of `~/.npm`. Big thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some time I ran into similar problems. In fact I was the owner of the `~/.npm` directory itself, not the root. But my problem was that some of the content of `~/.npm` was mine and some was root's. That's why installing some modules worked and installing others failed. It probably happened because of me using npm install in wrong way.

Following command fixed the issue:

```
sudo chown -R tducin:tducin ~/.npm
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to rep so...

Is there anything in the debug log? 
`/home/tducin/Development/qunit-sinon/npm-debug.log`

It doesn't look like it's trying to install globally as global modules are usually in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` or `/usr/lib/node_modules`

Please post the result of:

```
ls -l -a /home/tducin/ | grep npm
```

As the .npm folder may have been created as root